# connecting nodes on imageview by using canvas to draw

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw

Is it possible to allocate nodes on an Imageview and then connecting the nodes by using canvas draw ?
I am actually doing a simple navigation apps whereby i load a simple map into imageview and allocate few nodes on the map, the path will be drawn in between the nodes.

Thanks !

Comment: What is 'allocate nodes on an ImageView'. If you just want to draw points that look like nodes, it is possible to do it using `Canvas`.

Comment: sorry for the vague description. What i want to do is assign few "invisible" points on the image. and connecting the dots using lines based on the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You may override `ImageView.onDraw(Canvas)` like this :

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (isShowingNodes()) {
        Point[] nodes = getNodes();
        for (int i=1; i<nodes.length; ++i)
            canvas.drawLine(nodes[i-1].x, nodes[i-1].y, nodes[i].x, nodes[i].y, myPaint);
    }
}
```

Better rendering can be made, for example drawing circles to better materialize nodes.